# Is there any clean and easy way to disable continuous world with Mapbox iOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox

While working on fixing an app which uses the Mapbox API for iOS, I stumbled on a problem: I need to disable the "Continuous world" option on the map (the feature that allows the map to repeat itself indefinitely).

So far, I've found a workaround I am not content with, since it is more a hack than a fix, and it doesn't behave as expected; by setting the visibleCoordinateBounds to [(lat:-90°, long:-179.9°), (lat:90°, long:180°)]. I saw that the JS version of the API allows for a clean way to do this (with an appropriately named "continuousWorld" property), but I have found nothing of the sort in the official documentation or on Google for that matter.

So is there any better way of doing so?

Comment: You might check out [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/constraining-gestures/), though I’m unsure if it can handle world-sized bounds.